# The project ‘Project-Name’ is damaged and cannot be opened due to a parse error

Tags: xcode, git

The project ‘Project-Name’ is damaged and cannot be opened due to a parse error. Examine the project file for invalid edits or unresolved source control conflicts.

Other solutions online describe that there are unresolved conflicts in the actual project file: `project.pbxproj`

However, this makes no sense since I manually specified to take all incoming changes with:

```
git merge {Branch-Name} --strategy-option theirs
```

I also have tried a regular merge and resolved the conflicts manually in vim since the project cannot be opened with Xcode.

Additionally, there are no distinguished merge conflicts in the `project.pbxproj` because a cmd+f with arguments of `<<<<` `>>>>` or `====` yields no results in the entire file.

Also, this happens frequently with the project and I am unsure why. perhaps there is an issue with my `.gitignore`?

```
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
firebase-debug.log*

# Firebase cache
.firebase/

# Firebase config

# Uncomment this if you'd like others to create their own Firebase project.
# For a team working on the same Firebase project(s), it is recommended to leave
# it commented so all members can deploy to the same project(s) in .firebaserc.
# .firebaserc

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# Bower dependency directory (https://bower.io/)
bower_components

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules/

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history

# Output of 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Yarn Integrity file
.yarn-integrity

# Mac OS X
*.DS_Store

# Xcode
*.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
*.xcuserstate
Bucket.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/

# Cocoapodsl
Pods/
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, this makes no sense since I manually specified to take all incoming changes with:
>
> ```
> git merge {Branch-Name} --strategy-option theirs
> ```

This does not help any.  The files you are talking about are XML files, and Git's merge algorithm does not merge these correctly.  The `-X theirs` or `--strategy-option theirs` simply tells Git to *believe* it merged them correctly, even though it did not.

You *must* merge these files manually—or write an XML merge program, but this is so difficult that nobody has done it yet.  Or, don't merge the project file at all: write a new one, using whatever project-file writer software you have available.  (You could also literally take their file, *after* allowing a merge conflict, with `git checkout --theirs`; but this might lose important information from your own side of the merge.)

Comment: This makes a lot more sense thank you. Would something like XcodeGen alleviate merge issues like this? Recommended this from a Reddit post.

Comment: I know nothing of XcodeGen, I just know that merging XML is really hard. :-) (I've done a bit of work and research on diff and merge algorithms.)

Comment: no worries, that sounds interesting. thanks for the help!